# which journal service holds reboot logs in ubuntu

Tags: server

I need to get host reboot and shutdown logs using journald system service unit but i see only commands to get reboot and shutdown logs.do we have any service to get reboot logs using systemd service unit.
**Ex**: **journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=systemd-update-utmp.service**

I want to know which service holds all system reboot logs and shutdown logs.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know which service holds all system reboot logs and shutdown logs.

It is not a systemd.service that does that. systemd often depends on the older commands already available.

```
journalctl -b -1 -n
```

will show it but that one probes last. You can also use

```
last -x shutdown reboot
```

option `-n{digit}`  will limit it to {digit} results and show both shutdowns and reboots.

---

Examples

```
 last -x shutdown reboot
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Mon Aug 24 18:25   still running
shutdown system down  5.4.0-42-generic Mon Aug 24 17:55 - 18:25  (00:29)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Mon Aug 24 17:28 - 17:55  (00:27)
shutdown system down  5.4.0-42-generic Mon Aug 24 08:00 - 17:28  (09:27)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Mon Aug 24 07:31 - 08:00  (00:29)
shutdown system down  5.4.0-42-generic Mon Aug 24 06:54 - 07:31  (00:37)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Sun Aug 23 08:43 - 06:54  (22:10)
shutdown system down  5.4.0-42-generic Sun Aug 23 03:25 - 08:43  (05:17)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-42-generic Sun Aug 23 02:21 - 03:25  (01:04)
shutdown system down  5.4.0-42-generic Sat Aug 22 23:52 - 02:21  (02:29)
```

and

```
- Logs begin at Tue 2020-03-03 17:27:53 CET, end at Mon 2020-08-24 18:57:10 CE>
aug 24 17:55:45 discworld systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Syst>
aug 24 17:55:45 discworld systemd[1]: Reached target Shutdown.
aug 24 17:55:45 discworld systemd[1]: Reached target Final Step.
aug 24 17:55:45 discworld systemd[1]: systemd-poweroff.service: Succeeded.
aug 24 17:55:45 discworld systemd[1]: Finished Power-Off.
aug 24 17:55:45 discworld systemd[1]: Reached target Power-Off.
aug 24 17:55:45 discworld systemd[1]: Shutting down.
aug 24 17:55:45 discworld systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block de>
aug 24 17:55:45 discworld systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining pro>
aug 24 17:55:45 discworld systemd-journald[399]: Journal stopped
```

Comment: Hi Rinzwind,
I cant use the above commands as i m using splunk to get logs of vm and it works internally
systemd service units not on commands and vm os **container optimized** os wer the commands last reboot and all dont work.
So checking like can be use systemd service unit to get vm reboot/shutdown logs?